# Selenium Grid restarts every time a node is killed

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

**TL;DR; if a node in Selenium Grid dies, the Selenium Hub gets restarted. Why?**

I'm using Selenium Grid in Kubernetes using the file from https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/selenium.

I have noticed that every time a Chrome or Firefox node is killed because it reaches the resource limits, the Hub also restarts, eventually disconnecting all the other nodes for a couple of minutes. Why? Is this the expected behavior? I was expecting just a node getting disconnected but all other nodes be available.

It's not related to Kubernetes, as I have reproduced the issue in Docker Swarm as well. Also, it's not specific about a version of Selenium, I have reproduced it with 3.7, 3.11 and the latest 3.12.

Actually, it's quite easy to reproduce, just launch the Grid limiting the nodes to 500MB, launch them  to Youtube and eventually one will crash. When this happens, you will not be able to even access the Grid's console because it crashed as well.

I've noticed that the issue only triggers when a node crashed. If you just kill the node (e.g. `docker rm -f selenium-node-firefox-x62gxj`), everything is fine and it will rejoin the Grid without any disruptions.

Below is the relevant code, although I think this is an issue with the Grid directly.

```
def get_driver(browser, selenium_grid):
    if browser == 'CHROME':
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required')
        capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
    else:
        capabilities = getattr(DesiredCapabilities, browser)
    return webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=selenium_grid,
        desired_capabilities=capabilities
    )



driver = get_driver(browser, selenium_grid)
driver.get(channel_url)
```

`channel_url` is the link to a youtube video. `selenium_grid` the URL of the grid and `browser` a string "CHROME" or "FIREFOX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got my answer in #selenium channel in IRC.

The reason is the following:

> when a node dies, the hub removes it by querying it a few times and
>   after no answer it removes it. While that happens, if you get the grid
>   console, it gets slow (some internals how the node list is managed, we
>   should improve that) and since it gets slow, I imagine that
>   livenessProbe timesout so perhaps that kills the hub and brings a new
>   one

Effectively increasing the health check, solves the issue.